# Javascript: How to transfer components of one array to another and limit the number of items transfered

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm creating a personal training web app where I have an array of predefined tasks called `tasks`. There's another array called `sessionTasks` that will have the tasks for the session. Code so far:

```
var tasks = [
["First Task",1,0],
["Second Task...",4,5],
["Third Task!",0,5]
];

var sessionTasks = [

]
```

**Note:** the numbers next to the tasks are the minutes and the seconds that the person has to complete the task.

```
function setUpSessionTasks() {


for(sessionFull = false, i = 0; sessionFull == false; i++) {

    var sessionTasksSeconds = 0;
    alert(sessionFull);

    //the seconds that exist in the session
    sessionTasksSeconds += (sessionTasks[i][1])*60 + sessionTasks[i][2];
    alert(sessionTasks[i][0] + sessionTasksSeconds);

    //the seconds of the task that's gonna be added
    var randTaskNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * tasks.length);
    newTaskSeconds = (tasks[randTaskNum][1])*60 + tasks[randTaskNum][2];

    //seconds left in the session to fill
    var sessionTasksSecondsToFill = 1200 - sessionTasksSeconds;


    if((sessionTasksSeconds + newTaskSeconds) < sessionTasksSecondsToFill) {
        sessionTasks.push(tasks[randTaskNum]);
    } else {
        sessionFull = true;
    }

    alert(sessionFull);

}

}
```

What I mean to do with the code above is to fill the `sessionTasks` with random tasks from `tasks`, until the time of the tasks in `sessionTasks` is equal or a little bit under of 1200 seconds. I'm probably doing something fundamentally wrong but this function just stops the whole page from working and it doesn't do what I meant it to do. I just put the alerts there for testing and the first one works but the second one doesn't and I don't understand why.

If I'm going about doing this all wrong then please help me to go the right direction, but if not, please just tell what's wrong in this code. Thank you.

*Side note: I couldn't think of a better title to the question.*

Comment: Why are you adding the seconds of the sessionTasks that you have not yet even defined: `sessionTasksSeconds += (sessionTasks[i][1])*60 + sessionTasks[i][2];` ?

Comment: you should use a recursive function for pushing a random item of first array in second array until you reach a total time limit (the recursive function should then break)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you had a few things mixed up:

- You were adding seconds to an entry `sessionTasksSeconds` before it even existed: `sessionTasksSeconds += (sessionTasks[i][1])*60 + sessionTasks[i][2];`
- With every iteration of your loop, you set `var sessionTasksSeconds = 0;`. So you could never possibly reach `1200`.
- For some reason, you subtracted the value of the seconds you already had from the total seconds (`var sessionTasksSecondsToFill = 1200 - sessionTasksSeconds;`) and then compared it to the seconds you already had.
- You don't need a forloop for this example, a `while` loop will do just fine.
- You defined `sessionFull` as a global variable (missing the `var` statement before the initial assignment) which might bring plenty of other problems.

I've tried to clean up the code a bit and reduce repetition as well.
Also, I would recommend to use `console.log` instead of `alert`. This way you see one item after another in your console and you don't have to click away every alert window.

Code:

```
var tasks = [
    ["First Task",1,0],
    ["Second Task...",4,5],
    ["Third Task!",0,5]
];

function setUpSessionTasks(tasks) {

    var sessionTasks = [];

    // Before you were always overwriting it in your loop
    var sessionTasksSeconds = 0;

    //seconds left in the session to fill
    var sessionTasksSecondsToFill = 1200;

    var sessionFull = false;

    while(sessionFull === false) {

        //the seconds of the task that's gonna be added
        var randTaskNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * tasks.length);
        newTaskSeconds = (tasks[randTaskNum][1])*60 + tasks[randTaskNum][2];

        if(sessionTasksSeconds + newTaskSeconds <= sessionTasksSecondsToFill) {
            sessionTasksSeconds += newTaskSeconds;
            sessionTasks.push(tasks[randTaskNum]);

            //the seconds that exist in the session
            console.log(sessionTasksSeconds);
        } else {
            console.log('Session full');
            sessionFull = true;
        }
    }

}

setUpSessionTasks(tasks);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4rxe9sww/3/

As mentioned above in a comment, using a recursive strategy, you might get better results and get closer to the `1200` seconds, but this at least makes your example work.

Comment: This worked perfectly :-) The only change I made was I put the declaration of the vars inside the `setUpSessionTasks()` function and it still works. Your answer was very clear, I'd upvote more if I could :-)